# problem with java.sql.date

Tags: java, jdbc

```
 public java.sql.Date getDate()
{
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(2001, 10, 10);
    return date;

}
```

this function is in calendar class that own wrote it.

now in another class i wrote :

```
calendar c = new calendare();
java.sql.date d = c.getDate();
```

what value must store in d?it must be `2001,10,10` but it is `3901,11,10`!!!!!
why?
please help me in solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(2001 - 1900, 10, 10);
```

See [`java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) which says:

> year - the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)

That constructor is deprecated. You should prefer to use the other [`java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the docs for java.sql.Date

```
year - the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)
month - 0 to 11
day - 1 to 31
```

Also this constructor is deprecated. The year value is added tp 1900

Answer (score 0):

First, that constructor is deprecated, you shouldn't use it.

Second, the JavaDoc mentions:

```
Parameters:
    year - the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. 
    (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)
```

So according to the docs, you did specify the year `2001 + 1900` which is `3901` :-)